# Hibernate : Is there a call back method for intimating close of session

Tags: java, hibernate

Does Hibernate provide any event or call back method to inform when a session has been closed?

Comment: No. There is isn't any explicit callback to inform when session is closed. You can share the specific usecase where you think you need to have this callback. Someone may be able to suggest alternate approach.

Comment: @Gaurav : I am using getCurrentSession() and want to track when the session is closed by Hibernate as this task is done by Hibernate when using the above method. I have heard that it happens at tx commit but want to be sure.

Comment: Session is not closed automatically when tx.commit() is called. Session is closed when session.close() is called explicitly by the user. However , I would encourage you to read more on Session and Transaction to understand how session is handled.

Comment: @Gaurav, I am pretty sure that session is closed when tx commits in case one is using getCurrentSession() and ThreadLocalSessionContext. Only that I am not aware when this happens and this is something I want to track.